# Environment.NewLine does not work in Mono C#

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, mono, rtf

I use RichTextBox in an Windows Forms application written on C#, which I try launch on Ubuntu with the command

```
mono TestApp.exe
```

the application starts and runs almost all the functionality except the new line in RichTextBox. So, under Windows, the text is transferred to a new line, and in Linux the text goes in one line after large interval.

```
rtbTest.AppendText(_text.Status + Environment.NewLine);
```

Then I'll try use Rtf with generated string like this:

```
string r = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\deff0\deflang1049{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset204 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
                    \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs29 Goodbye, World!\line\par\n }";
        rtbTest.Multiline = true;

        rtbTest.Rtf = r;
```

it's also doesn't work also when I running app in Windows now. What should I do to get new line?

Comment: download the "Mono Migration Analyzer" (MoMA), which is a tool specifically designed to identify unresolved dependencies and help you solve the problem.

Comment: I tried many examples but have same result. But I found warning in linux console when I ran application : ` Gtk- [1;33mWARNING [0m **: Locale not supported by C library.         Using the fallback 'C' locale. `